# Convergence of function sequence in $C([0,1])$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I want to calculate limit of $f_n = (1-x)^n$ in $C([0,1])$

**My work so far**

Let's pick $f \equiv 1$. Of course $f \in C([0,1])$

Now I want to consider expression $\|f_n-f\|$

$$ \|f_n-f\|_{\infty}  = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|(1-x)^n-1| = 0 \rightarrow0$$

So out of these facts I can claim that such defined $f$ is really a limit of $f_n$. Is my explanation correct ? If yes- could you please show me how to formally prove that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|(1-x)^n-1| = 0$ ? I see intuitevly that this supremum has to be zero, becuase $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|(1-x)^n| = 1$, however I'm not so sure how to actually show this. Could you pleqae give me a hand ?

Comment: No, your calculations are not correct. Notice that for $x = 1$, we have $\left| \left( 1 - x \right)^n - 1 \right| = 1$. Therefore, $\sup\limits_{x \in \left[ 0, 1 \right]} \left| \left( 1 - x \right)^n - 1 \right| \neq 0$. Also, if you draw some graphs of the first few functions, you will understand that the sequence of functions does not converge in $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct. In fact $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n$ does not converge in $C[0,1]$, that is there is no $f\in C[0,1]$ to which $f_n$ converges uniformly. To wit:

1. The sequence $f_n$ converges point wise to $F(x)=\mathbb{1}_{\{0\}}(x)$, that is $F(0)=1$ and $F(x)=0$ in $0<x\leq1$.
2. As $F\notin C[0,1]$, convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 5):

No, your answer is wrong. $(1-x)^{n} \to 0$ if $x>0$ and it tends to $1$ if $x=0$. Since the limit  is not continuous we cannot have uniform convergence. Thus,  this sequence is not convergent in $C[0,1]$.